# Display a div on mouse enter, cannot be seen if mouse position is in the right-most

Tags: javascript, css

I have a simple code to display a div when hovering a div, like this below

```
$(".dhx_project").mouseenter(function(e) {
    $('.project-tooltip').css({
        left: e.pageX + 20,
        top: e.pageY
    });
});
```

My problem is when user try put the mouse on the "RIGHT-MOST" of the ".dhx-project" div, the hover div cannot be seen like this

[image]

Is there's a way to put a condition when user mouseenter on the right-most, the div will show on the left?

SAMPLE SNIPPET
https://jsfiddle.net/johndavemanuel/2jxfLw1z/14/

Comment: add a runnable snippet, or at least add your `HTML`/`CSS` codes.

Comment: This can be easily achieved using `pseudo` classes with css.

Comment: hi! I have include a sample snippet to demo the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend you mouseenter handler to account for this edge case, by calculating the position and dimensions of the tooltip relative to the screen width.

With this, you'd determine if the tooltip is falling outside of the screen - in that case, you could set the `right:0` property of the tooltip to align the tooltip to the right edge of the screen like so:

```
$(".dhx_project").mouseenter(function(e) {

    $('.project-tooltip').show();

    // Extract data used to determine if tooltip will be off screen
    var left = e.pageX + 20;
    var width =  $('.project-tooltip').width()
    var styles = {
        position : 'absolute',
        top: e.pageY + 5    
    }    

  // If the right edge of the tooltip is out of the screen ..
  if(left + width > $(document).width()) {

    // .. then re-adjust it's position to "hug" the right 
    // edge of the screen 
    styles.left = 'auto';
    styles.right = 0;
  }
  else {
    styles.left = left;
    styles.right = 'auto';  
  }

  // Apply styles to tooltip
  $('.project-tooltip').css(styles);
});
```

[UPDATED] Here's [a working jsFiddle also](https://jsfiddle.net/2jxfLw1z/50/)

#### Update: Prevent tooltip disappearing off bottom of page

Here's [an updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jxfLw1z/68/) showing how to keep the tooltip from disappearing off the bottom of the page

Note also that this updated solution requires a small update to your CSS to improve reliability:

```
.project-tooltip {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none; /* <-- Add this */
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering but it seems it is still on right like this
https://jsfiddle.net/johndavemanuel/2jxfLw1z/17/

Comment: Hi @DaveManuel just updated answer with jsFiddle and adjustments to script - does this help?

Comment: Hello Denny! Thanks for your effort! but it seems the same when I try to hover on right most part

Comment: @DaveManuel that's strange - seems to be working for me. I'm using Chrome by the way. Perhaps you're using a different browser?

Comment: I am also using Chrome., latest version. is this normal?
https://imgur.com/a/pQasP3z

Comment: @DaveManuel interesting - just updated the jsFiddle link in answer with a different solution, does that work for you?

Comment: Hi! Seems okay now, I will try to implement on the actual system

Comment: @DaveManuel great! Let me know if you have any difficulty with it

Comment: Hi! It is working great, but my issue now is the div "dhx_project" because many it reaches the browsr bottom and tool tip is on the bottom, how can I position the tooltip?

Comment: Great to hear it's working, not sure I understand - are you finding that the tooltip goes out of screen if the user scrolls to the bottom of the page?

Comment: @DaveManuel please see updated answer - hope this helps you!

Comment: if the DIv is in the "RIGHT-BOTTOM part, I cannot see the hover that is what I mean
https://jsfiddle.net/johndavemanuel/2jxfLw1z/76/

Answer (score 2):

You  can have 2 divs inside the header and have 2 different mouseenter events, then calculate different left and right values and achieve what you want.

I fixed the tooltip's width with `width: 50%` to make it consistent but you can also give another width yourself.

```js
$(".dhx_1").mouseenter(function(e) {
  showTooltip(e.pageX + 20, '', e.pageY)
});

$(".dhx_2").mouseenter(function(e) {
  showTooltip('', $('body').width() - e.pageX + 20, e.pageY)
});

$(".dhx_project").mouseleave(function(e) {
  $('.project-tooltip').hide(100);
});

function showTooltip(left, right, top) {
  $('.project-tooltip').show(100);
  $('.project-tooltip').css({
    right: right,
    left: left,
    top: top
  });
}
```

```css
.dhx_project {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  height: 30px;
}

.dhx_project .dhx_1,
.dhx_project .dhx_2 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
}

.dhtmlXTooltip.tooltip[role=tooltip] {
  font-size: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.dhtmlXTooltip.tooltip {
  border-left: 1px dotted #e0e0e0;
  border-top: 1px dotted #e0e0e0;
  font-family: Roboto, Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  z-index: 10;
}

.project-tooltip {
  display: none;
  width: 50%
}

.dhtmlXTooltip.tooltip {
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888;
  -o-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color='#888888', Direction=135, Strength=5);
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dhx_project">
  <div class='dhx_1'>
  </div>
  <div class='dhx_2'>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="dhtmlXTooltip tooltip project-tooltip" role="tooltip" style="left: 683px; top: 271px;">
  <p>
    <b id="project-title">Title:</b>
    <span id="project-title-holder">bug fix 196 3</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span id="project-duration">11-Sep-2018 09:53 am - 12-Sep-2018 09:53 am</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b id="project-description">Description:</b>
    <span id="project-description-holder"> </span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b id="project-leader">Leader:</b>
    <span id="project-leader-holder">Hiro Ishida</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b id="project-member">Member:</b>
    <span id="project-member-holder">Michael Robert, Freddie Mars, Sheryl Minh, Masao Takahashi, Huy Huy, Quang Tuấn Huy Ngô, Thùy Linh Đỗ, </span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b id="project-budget">Budget:</b>
    <span id="project-budget-holder">JPY 111</span>
  </p>
</div>
```