# Is it possible to dynamically position a "tooltip" (div) such that it does not go outside the window using only CSS?

Tags: css, css-position

I have code that makes popups (I recommended to do this by an accessibility consultant) based on focus using only CSS and tag attributes.  It works great until the focused element is too near the right side or bottom of the window, and then I need specific markup to flip the tooltip to the other side of (or above) the focused element.

I'd like to have generic CSS that "just works" without knowing the placement of the focused element ahead of time (this is for a responsive layout that reflows for different window sizes)

I know I can solve this with Javascript, and there is already a question talking about that ([Display a div on mouse enter, cannot be seen if mouse position is in the right-most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267910/display-a-div-on-mouse-enter-cannot-be-seen-if-mouse-position-is-in-the-right-m/52268009#52268009)) but I'd really like to do it using only CSS.

Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/e6g39Lvb/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<p>
<input type="text" /> Place cursor here and hit "tab" key to move focus
</p>
<a href="#" title="this is just an example link that does nothing">example link 1</a>
<div class="rightside">
<a href="#" title="this is just an example link that does nothing">example link 2</a>
<br />
<a class="corrected" href="#" title="this only works if I already know it's on the right edge of the screen">example link 3</a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
  margin: 1em;
}
.rightside{
  text-align: right;
}
*:not(:hover):focus{
  position:relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
*[title]:not(:hover):focus:after { /* show tooltip on focus but user default for hover */
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #fc0;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    color: black;
    background: #fffea1;
    content: attr(title) !important;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    min-width: 5em;
    max-width: 15em;
    transform: translate(0.5em,-30%);
}
.corrected[title]:not(:hover):focus:after {
      transform: translate(-100%,-30%);
      left: -0.5em;
}
```

Just to be clear:  I know to achieve this with JS, I'm looking for a CSS only answer (if it's possible)